# Dynamically generate arguments for python script input

Tags: bash, command-line, python, xargs

I call a python script with some command line arguments like:

```
python3 script.py --run 1 --filepath "this/file/dir"
```

I now try to parse the arguments from a config file with:

```
grep -v '^#' ${THIS_FILE_DIR}/model.conf | sed 's/=/ /' | xargs  -I% echo "--%"
```

This yields my desired string:

```
--run 1
--filepath this/file/dir
```

Is there a way to input this string dynamically into my python command, something along the lines of:

```
python3 script.py $(grep -v '^#' ${THIS_FILE_DIR}/model.conf | sed 's/=/ /' | xargs  -I% echo "--%")
```

Conf File for references

```
# vars
run=1
filepath=this/file/dir
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have multiple choices, since you already use `sed`, I would suggest

```
python3 script.py $(sed -e '/^#/d' -e 's/=/ /' -e 's/^/--/' ${THIS_FILE_DIR}/model.conf )
```

where

- use `-e` to specify multiple sed commands
- `'/^#/d'` delete lines starting with `#`
- `'s/^/--/'` replace start of line by `--`

Comment: cool, I found another solution but yours is more concise!